# increment or de-increment on button press

Tags: javascript, php

The form code:

```
<td>
    <form action="cart.php" method="get">
        <input type="button" onclick="buttonSubtract1()" name="subtract1" 
               value="-"/>
        <input type="text" size="4" id="qty1" name="quantity1" value="0"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="buttonAdd1()" name="add1" value="+"/>
        <input type="submit" name="product1" value="Add"/>
    </form>
</td>
```

The javascript:

```
var i = 0;
var qty1 =  document.getElementById('qty1').value;
function buttonAdd1() {
    document.getElementById('qty1').value = ++i;
}
function buttonSubtract1() {
if (qty1 > 0) {
    document.getElementById('qty1').value = --i;}
}
```

I changed the code to increment and de-increment using javascript which worked fine so I tried to make it so that de-incrementation only works if the number is positive but now incrementing is working fine but it is not allowing de-incrementation of any number. Why is this?

Comment: What does $_GET contain?

Comment: show you full code ,where is your submit button ? how you are sending the form data?

Comment: It's because qty is set on page load and never updated. Check my answer. Nothing to do with $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['subtract1'])) { 
    $quantity1 = $_GET['$quantity1'];
    $quantity1--;
}
?>

<?php if (isset($_GET['add1'])) { 
    $quantity1 = $_GET['$quantity1'];
    $quantity1++;
}
?>

<form action="cart.php" method="get">
     <input type="submit" name="subtract1" value="-"/>
     <input type="text" size="4" name="$quantity1" value="<?php echo $quantity1 ?>"/>
     <input type="submit" name="add1" value="+"/>
```

Comment: How can you add or subtract from a button?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.
Make sure the php code is above the html (so that the data gets processed before you output it) :

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['quantity1'])) {
    $quantity1 = intval($_GET['quantity1']);
    if(isset($_GET['subtract1'])) { 
        $quantity1--;
    } else if (isset($_GET['add1'])) {
        $quantity1++;
    }
}
?>
<td>
<form action="cart.php" method="get">
    <input type="button" name="subtract1" value="-" />
    <input type="text" size="4" name="quantity1" value="<?php echo $quantity1; ?>" />
    <input type="button" name="add1" value="+" />
    <input type="submit" name="product1" value="Add" />
</form>
</td>
```

Comment: before isset($_GET['quantity1']) do you have $quantity1 set to any value ? or what exactly doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is to get a reference to the object (qty1) then test or change the properties as required. This code seems to do what is required. It sends the appropriate values as the '$_GET' parameters as checked in PHP.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <script type = 'text/javascript'>
        var rfvGlobal = {};
        function buttonAdd1() {
            rfvGlobal.qty1.value++;
        }
        function buttonSubtract1() {
            if (rfvGlobal.qty1.value > 0) {
                rfvGlobal.qty1.value--;
            }
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

<table>
<td><form action="" method="get">
     <input type="button" onclick="buttonSubtract1()" name="subtract1" value="-"/>
     <input type="text" size="4" id="qty1" name="quantity1" value="0"/>
     <input type="button" onclick="buttonAdd1()" name="add1" value="+"/>
     <input type="submit" name="product1" value="Add"/>
 </form></td>
 </table>  
 <script>
    rfvGlobal.qty1 = document.getElementById('qty1');
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[View this working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pH5d2/)**

Your problem is that you aren't checking that the element's value, just `qty1` which was set on page load but never updated.

```
function buttonSubtract1() {
    var qtyElement = document.getElementById('qty1'); // the element
    if (qtyElement.value > 0) qtyElement.value = --i; // if its value at this point in time >0 change it
}
```

The above fixes your current code, but...

Why don't you write less (this is the only function you need)

```
function buttonAlter(which, byWhat){
    var qtyElement = document.getElementById('qty' + which);
    if (byWhat > 0 || qtyElement.value > 0) qtyElement.value = parseInt(qtyElement.value) + byWhat;    
}
```

for more buttons

```
<form action="cart.php" method="get">
     <input type="button" onclick="buttonAlter(1, -1)" name="subtract1" value="-"/>
     <input type="text" size="4" id="qty1" name="quantity1" value="0"/>
     <input type="button" onclick="buttonAlter(1, 1)" name="add1" value="+"/>
     <input type="submit" name="product1" value="Add"/>
    <br />
     <input type="button" onclick="buttonAlter(2, -1)" name="subtract1" value="-"/>
     <input type="text" size="4" id="qty2" name="quantity1" value="0"/>
     <input type="button" onclick="buttonAlter(2, 1)" name="add1" value="+"/>
     <input type="submit" name="product1" value="Add"/>
    <br />
     <input type="button" onclick="buttonAlter(3, -1)" name="subtract1" value="-"/>
     <input type="text" size="4" id="qty3" name="quantity1" value="0"/>
     <input type="button" onclick="buttonAlter(3, 1)" name="add1" value="+"/>
     <input type="submit" name="product1" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

**[This version's demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pH5d2/1/)**